# Como pegar o value de um input que foi autocompletado (React)?

Tags: javascript, react

A ideia é após preencher o campo cep, o consumo da api preenche o restante dos inputs porém após isso não estou conseguindo pegar o value desses inputs que foram autocompletados, ele retorna como array vazio...

```
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'

const {register, setValue} = useForm("")
  const [cep, setCEP] = useState("")
  const [address, setStreet] = useState("")
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("")
  const [neighborhood, setNeighborhood] = useState("")
  const [city, setCity] = useState("")
  const [state, setState] = useState("")

const checkCEP = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const cep = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "")
    console.log(cep)

    fetch(`https://ws.apicep.com/cep/${cep}.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {console.log(data)
        setValue('address', data.address)
        setValue('district', data.district)
        setValue('city', data.city)
        setValue('state', data.state)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      
  }

 return (
<div className='personalInfos'>
            <label>
              <span>CEP:</span>
                <input type="text" 
                      name='cep'
                      {...register("cep")} 
                      onBlur={checkCEP}
                      onChange={(e) => setCEP(e.target.value)}
                      value={cep}      
                />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Rua:</span>
                <input type="text" 
                       {...register("address")} 
                        name="address"
                        onChange={(e, value) => setStreet(value)} 
                        value={address}   
                />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Número:</span>
                <input type="number"  
                       name='number'
                       onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
                       value={number}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Bairro:</span>
                <input type="text" 
                      {...register("district")} 
                      name="neighborhood"
                      onChange={(e) => setNeighborhood(e.target.value)}
                      value={neighborhood}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Cidade:</span>
                <input type="text" 
                       {...register("city")} 
                       name="city"
                       onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
                       value={city} 
                />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Estado:</span>
                <input type="text" 
                      {...register("state")} 
                      name="state"
                      onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
                      value={state}     
                />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className='btn'>
           <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
          </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notei que está usando react-hook-form, com ele você não precisa se preocupar em declarar um state pra cada input (apenas o **...register()** é o suficiente), os valores você poderá pegar através se colocar em volta do seu formulário um "" e de dentro dele o *onSubmit*

Caso queira acessar o valor do Input antes de enviar o formulário, você pode extrair do **useForm** o metodo **watch**.

```
const thisAddress = watch("address");
```

**thisAddress** terá o valor do Input preenchido pela sua chamada API;